# System.Exception when trying to load designer for Windows Universal Blank App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm receiving this error when I try to load the designer for a Windows Universal Blank App. I'm currently using VS2015.

I did a VS2015 repair to see if it fixed the issue, but it remained the same. The error is:

```
System.Exception
To install this application you need either a Windows developer license or 
a sideloading-enabled system.

Deployment of package failed because no valid license or sideloading 
policy could be applied. 
A developer license (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or 
enterprise sideloading configuration (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) 
may be required.
```

And this is the screenshot. What can the issue be?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have developer mode option enabled?
It should be set in the "Settings" like below:

[image]

[image]